# What is a light-weight OS X server?

Tags: mac-osx-server, html

After writing `foo.html` with some CSS and some JavaScript, I test it on Safari, Firefox, and Chrome, and see that all is well.

I'd now like to debug the files on iOS and Android.

What is the lightest weight server I can launch from the command line? I would like to run in the Terminal:

```
> runserver .
```

to be able subsequently to point browsers to, say, `http://192.168.5.2/foo.html` on either an Android or an iOS device on the local network, and see the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OSX, Python's SimpleHTTPServer is probably your best bet.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

will serve the current directory at `http://localhost:8000/`

Comment: Perfect, yet somehow incomplete! I can look at what `netstat` says and figure out the IP to connect to from other machines/devices on the network. If you know of a command-line statement that will produce just the IP needed, please share it.

Comment: @Calaf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322485/how-to-i-get-the-primary-ip-address-of-the-local-machine-on-linux-and-os-x

Comment: This is great. It should be in everyone's ~/.bash_profile. I'm puzzled by the downvotes. I wish they would state their objections. Is stackoverflow a better fit than serverfault for this kind of question?

Comment: Neither one's really a fit. Both consider your question off-topic.

Comment: ... the 150+ upvotes on the answer you kindly shared notwithstanding, that is :)